# Update and Insert into MERGE query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query :

```
MERGE INTO member_staging x
USING (SELECT member_id, first_name, last_name, rank, startdate, enddate FROM members) y
ON (x.member_id  = y.member_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET x.first_name = y.first_name, 
                        x.last_name = y.last_name, 
                        x.rank = y.rank,
                        enddate = GETDATE();
    WHERE x.first_name <> y.first_name OR 
           x.last_name <> y.last_name OR 
           x.rank <> y.rank 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT(x.member_id, x.first_name, x.last_name, x.rank)  
    VALUES(y.member_id, y.first_name, y.last_name, y.rank);
```

I want to INSERT the new record after the update with the new values and the SYSDATE in startdate
and 9999/12/31 in the enddate.

Here is an example :

```
member_id first_name last_name rank startdate  enddate
1         John       LeBlanc   12   2021/09/10 9999/12/31
```

If the record is updated , the rank becomes 9 :

```
member_id first_name last_name rank startdate  enddate
1         John       LeBlanc   12   2021/09/10 2021/09/16
1         John       LeBlanc   9    2021/09/17 9999/12/31
```

The old version will be updated and a new version will be added with adding +1 to startdate to avoid overlapping.

Comment: It almost sounds like you're trying to implement your own [temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables). :)

Comment: Add a trigger to update the previous rows' end dates.  (Match on id & startdate, update if the match, insert if they don't, then the trigger modifies the previous rows if an insert occurs.)  But, a single source row in a MERGE is ***not*** going to trigger both the UPDATE and the INSERT.

Comment: Or, use an `OUTPUT` clause to pass the inserted rows to another statement, allowing the data from `inserted` to then be used in a separate `UPDATE`.

Comment: @RichardDeeming I'm sorry I put the wrong database it is Oracle

Comment: @MatBailie is it possible with Oracle ?

Comment: Marking as SQL-Server in error, again?  I'd use the trigger in Oracle, or a stored procedure *(Use MERGE for correcting existing rows or adding new rows, then run another update using the same source data, with the necessary logic to identify the rows where the end dates need updating)*.  I would ***not*** try to mangle it all in to a huge single `MERGE`.

Comment: what you are trying to implement sounds like a kind of **SCD Slow Change Dimension** , as you want to keep a track based on the validity of the records ( startdate-enddate). I would use a normal trigger for this if the changes are not often, or a compound trigger if the merge is affecting  a huge number of rows